# Spring Security OAuth client

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to build two applications based on Spring Security OAuth2:

- oauth server
- oauth client

Token store is my custom implementation based on CouchBase and available for both applications, so communication between those two application is not needed. First application puts data into CouchBase bucket and the second one should be available to read it.

Unfortunately I noticed the following problem on the oauth client application when http rules are added:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add a gobal <authentication-manager> element to your configuration (with child <authentication-provider> elements)? Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on your <http> and <global-method-security> elements.
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:31) [spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20) [spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 66 more
```

On the server side this error does not occur, because I have following in application context:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I am not able to provide this authentication manager on the client side, because userService implementation is not available here.

Do you have any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you paste your complete file please ?

Comment: You can find full example here: https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider

Comment: have you having issues for run the referenced github project ?

Comment: Do you even need the Spring Security filter chain in your client app? (If you just want to get an access token you only need the OAuth2ClientContextFilter from Spring OAuth.) If you do need it, you might have to provide an empty authentication manager, just to keep the XML parser happy. Might be nicer not to use XML?

Comment: @Pracede referenced github project is ok until http rules are removed.

Comment: @Dave Syer - You are right - I had to do that (provide fake AuthManager) since Spring OAuth factories that are used to create objects from xml requires this even if it is not used. It is the only workaround that I found.